# Read bmp file in to array

Tags: c++, image, file

I have a bmp file 50x50 and array[50][50] and I want to put pixels color to array

pixel 1.1 to array[0][0]
pixel 2.1 to array[2][0]

ect.

or how to put image on screen using  lib

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a look at [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), which will take the legwork out of working with images.

Answer (score 0):

[EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/)  is a nice simple library too, if you're using C++